# how to show point in printf "%s\n" 10000?

Tags: bash, printf

i have command `printf "%s\n"`. I want that command can separated zero with point (`.000`).

e.g:

`printf "%s\n" 300.77`

`300.77`

I want

`printf "%s\n" 1000000`

`1.000.000`

Would you help me, to solved my problem?

Comment: Have you tried googling for the possible conversion specifiers of `printf()`? It doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 5):

You would have to use the `%f` format to specify that the value is to be treated as a floating point number.

```
$ printf "%7.4f\n" 12.2
12.2000
$ printf "%7.4f\n" 12.23576 12.23574
12.2358
12.2357
$
```

If the objective is to get the local thousands separator into the output, then you need support for the `'` modifier in `printf()` formats:

```
$ printf "%'d\n" 1223576 1223574
1,223,576
1,223,574
$
```

The behaviour is locale-dependent:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
$ (export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8; printf "%'d\n" 1223576 1223574)
1223576
1223574
$ (export LANG=dk_DK.UTF-8; printf "%'d\n" 1223576 1223574)
1,223,576
1,223,574
$ (export LANG=it_IT.UTF-8; printf "%'d\n" 1223576 1223574)
1223576
1223574
$ (export LANG=gr_GR.UTF-8; printf "%'d\n" 1223576 1223574)
1,223,576
1,223,574
$
```

Tested on Mac OS X 10.8.3 (`bash` version: `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)`).

Comment: +1 didn't know the `'` modifier. Pretty cool!

Comment: @Jaypal: Support the `'` modifier is in the GNU C Library, and evidently Mac OS X (BSD) too; it is not in either Standard C or POSIX C.  Hang around SO enough and you learn these things — I only found out about it in the last month or so.

Comment: can I combine %'d\n and %s\n into a one command ??

Comment: If you want to: `printf "This is a number: %'d; and this is a string '%s'\n" 3141593 aleph`.  What are you really asking, and why don't you try it, and/or try reading the manual?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `'` is in Posix, see here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html . It's marked as `CX`, which means it's an extension to Standard C but "[a]pplication developers may make use of an extension as it is supported on all POSIX.1-2008-conforming systems".

Comment: @rici: you're right, the current version of the POSIX description for `printf()` does include the apostrophe.  In fact, it was even in the 2004 version of POSIX...I am not sure how I missed that, but I did.  It is not in ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (Standard C).  Thanks for pointing out my oversight.